# R - how to create dataframe of vectors with xy-coordinates

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates

Suppose I have the following 2 dataframes

```
dfx <- data.frame(z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), p = rpois(10,2), k = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
```

```
dfy <- data.frame(a = rpois(10,2), b = rpois(10,2), c = rpois(10,2), d = rpois(10,2), e = rpois(10,2))
```

with dfx consistent of a bunch of x-values and dfy consisting of a bunch of y-values - z partner to a, q partner to b, etc.). I want to create a dataframe where: 1) Every column is a x,y coordinate, so that it looks as follows

```
column1:    column2     column3:     column4:    column5:
z1,a1       q1,b1       p1,c1        k1,d1        t1,e1       
z2,a2       q2,b2       p2,c2        k2,d2        ...
z3,a3       q3,b3       p3,c3        ...          ...
z4,a4       q4,b4       ...          ...          ...
...         ...

etc.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `paste`

```
out <- data.frame(Map(paste, dfx, dfy, MoreArgs = list(sep=",")))
names(out) <- paste0("column", seq_along(out))
out
#   column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
#1      2,2     1,6     1,0     1,0     1,5
#2      3,2     3,3     1,2     2,2     0,1
#3      3,3     1,0     2,2     1,3     1,1
#4      2,2     5,3     2,4     4,1     1,0
#5      3,1     4,1     1,3     1,1     0,1
#6      4,1     1,2     3,2     2,1     1,5
#7      5,2     5,0     0,2     4,3     2,1
#8      3,0     2,5     4,2     5,4     4,2
#9      3,3     3,2     0,3     5,1     0,3
#10     4,2     2,2     0,1     4,3     5,1
```

Or if it needs to be a `list` column

```
Map(list, dfx, dfy)
```

---

Or if it is converted to `matrix`, `paste` can be directly applied

```
array(paste(as.matrix(dfx), as.matrix(dfy), sep=","), dim = dim(dfx),
      dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("column", seq_along(dfx))))
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we can use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map2_df(dfx, dfy, str_c, sep=",") %>%
    rename_all(~ str_c('column', seq_along(.)))
```

Answer (score 1):

One `base R` option could be:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(paste(unlist(dfx), unlist(dfy), sep = ","), dim(dfx)))
names(df) <- paste0("column", 1:length(df))

   column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
1      1,1     2,2     3,2     2,0     0,3
2      1,3     1,4     3,1     2,1     1,4
3      2,0     0,4     4,1     2,1     2,4
4      3,3     3,3     2,2     1,3     1,2
5      2,2     2,3     0,1     0,0     0,3
6      1,0     0,1     2,4     5,3     4,3
7      0,1     1,3     2,3     0,2     4,3
8      0,1     0,2     1,4     2,3     1,1
9      1,6     2,3     1,0     5,3     0,2
10     3,1     1,2     0,3     3,2     2,1
```